# scroll up to content in div tag when user clicks a button

Tags: html, scroll

When a user clicks a button on my page, it refreshes 2 divs with content from 2 different pages. The button is in the 2nd div.

I want it so when the button is clicked, it scrolls back up to a point on the main page. Usually its the `<a name=top>` thing but now i'm using divs I'm not sure how to go about this.

Layout like:

```
<page>
<- jump to here ->
<div1> data </div1>
<div2> buttons </div2>
</page>
```

The code in my main page is:

```
$(function() {
 $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $("#result").load($(this).data('url'), function () {
        $('#crimes').load('crimes_get.php');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your JavaScript should execute something along the lines of `document.body.scrollTop = 0;` (or some other value than `0`, e.g. `anchorElement.offsetTop` to scroll to a predefined element, but make sure you don't mess up offsetParents - see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetTop) for the reference.)

Comment: Not sure where I should add this, im not very good with javascript. Updated my orig post to show my jquery code

Comment: Ahh, not that good at jQuery, but my wild guess is:
    `$("#result").load($(this).data('url'), function () {
            $('#crimes').load('crimes_get.php', function() { /* insert the code here */});
        });`

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
$(function() {
  $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#result").load($(this).data('url'), function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0) //<------- THIS
    $('#crimes').load('crimes_get.php');
  });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an animation?

```
$(function() {
   $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#result").load($(this).data('url'), function () {
        var topPos = $("#targetDiv").offset().top;

        $("body").animate({"scrollTop": topPos}, 200)
        $('#crimes').load('crimes_get.php');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: theres no #targetdiv, its the main window/body i want to scroll. Is it possible to do that?